# Calling context managers in python

Tags: python, function, yield, contextmanager

I am trying to find a good way to explain why creating an specialized context manager by calling another one works as expected. I am not complaining!, it is great that it does. But I was not sure if that it would work until I tested it and therefore I feel I am loosing something.

Just to clarify considere the following example:

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager
>>> @contextmanager
... def f(val):
...    print(val)
...    yield
...    print(val+1)
...
>>>
>>> with f(1):
...  print(3)
...
1
3
2
```

And now we specialize it:

```
>>> def f42():
...    return f(42)
...
>>> with f42():
...    print(3)
...
42
3
43
```

I guess what is confusing me is why does the yield from f bubbles up through f42? Why I do not need to write f42 as a context manager explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no difference* between using `f(42)` in a `with` statement and using it in another function then returning it. All that `with` requires is that the *expression* produces a context manager.

You could also do this:

```
cm = f(42)
with cm:
    print(3)
```

All that Python does is execute the expression in the `with <expression>` statement and then treats the *result* of that expression as a context manager. How the expression produced that context manager is of no consequence.

In other words, `f` is not your context manager here, only the *return value* of a call to `f()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your last with statement, f42() gets evaluated and runs f(42) which is then used in the context of your with statement.